# Using Axis toolkit to generate C++ Stubs for Rally's SOAP interface

Tags: soap, axis, rally

I'm trying to use Rally's SOAP interface from my C++ application. Therefore I generated the C++ Stubs using the Axis 1.4 toolkit. Unfortunately the generated files contain compile errors. I fixed these errors manually and the Stubs do compile now. Nevertheless I have the impression that more things went wrong during code generation. E.g. I don't have a class called RallyServiceService as it is used in the .NET example:

```
// create a service object
RallyServiceService service = new RallyServiceService();

// set the service URL
service.Url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.32/RallyService";

...
```

Has anyone ever tried to access Rally's SOAP interface from C++? Any help how to start establishing a connection is appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a solution per se, I thought I would summarize the dialog I exchanged with Michael via a support case:

When using WSDL2Java to generate Java stubs, you get four classes related to the RallyServiceService piece, and these are language-specific, as they include RPC bindings, network connection classes, etc

The inability of the Axis C++ WSDL2Ws tool to formulate the RallyServiceService classes may be related to the fact that RallyServiceService, in java at least, is an interface used to extend javax.xml.rpc.Service. The Rally WSDL shows the interface definition:

```
  <wsdl:service name="RallyServiceService">
  <wsdl:port binding="impl:RallyServiceSoapBinding" name="RallyService">
  <wsdlsoap:address location="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/rallyservice" />
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Where the impl: keywoard that implies the RallyServiceSoapBinding class's promise to implement the methods defined in RallyServiceService.

I'm way out of my league when it comes to C++, but I don't think that C++ technically has an interface construct as a way of extending classes - interfaces are more of a Java/C# language construct. This may mean that this aspect of the Rally WSDL is a Java/C# - specific implementation, or at least cannot be easily translated into a C++ construct using the Axis WSDL2Ws tool.

It may be possible to write a custom C++ version of RallyServiceService and its associated classes, but it could be a bit tricky. If you have some success - please share the outcome here as there may be other Rally customers interested in a similar functionality.